# Azure & iOS: How to set up tagged push notifications in App Services NOT Mobile Services

Tags: ios, azure, apple-push-notifications

This guide doesn't touch tagging and nothing in the Mobile Apps SDK seems to mention anything about tagging.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started-push/

This Mobile Services guide works with tags but the prerequisites clearly state that it requires Mobile Services SDK and not App Services SDK. The two are incompatible.

Can anybody point me to a guide or explain how you're supposed to bridge the gap since MSFT doesn't?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am facing the same problem right now

Comment: Same here. The MS documentation on push notifications is absolutely abysmal. On top of that, there are at least 3 or 4 different SDKs that are not labelled coherently and are incompatible with each other. Complete fail MS